# How to you end an if-else loop without the program crashing?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I am creating an app in xcode where the user is asked a series of questions and they input an answer. (Don't worry, my question isn't xcode related) The questions and answers are both stored in arrays, and I have an if-else statement that prints out the question and recognizes the answer. I only have 5 questions in the array. Once the user submits the answer to question 5, the app crashes and an error stating "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" appears. How to I get the if-else statement to recognize that it has run out of questions in the array and get the program to move on to other lines of code?

I have already tried a series of different types of loops, like while, repeat, switch statements, and for loops. None of them are as successful as the if-else statement (meaning they crash sooner that the if-else does). I've also tried creating a if-else inside of the original statement. For example, I tried:
if (x >= 6){
return
} 
However, I still receive the same "Index out of range" error.

```
let question = ["What is the number 1?", "What is the number 2?", 
"What is the number 3?", "What is the number 4?", "What is the 
number 5?"]
    let answer = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    var x = 0

@IBAction func submissionButton(_ sender: Any) { 
      if answerBox.text! == answer[x]
            {
                x += 1
                print("correct")
                question.text = question[x]
                answerBox.text = ""

            }
       else if (x >= 6)
       {
            print("done")
            return
       {
       else
            {
                print("wrong")
                answerBox.text = ""
            }
}
```

Whenever I run the program and enter the questions, the app crashes after I answer "What is question 5?" and I get the error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" .  However, I wanted the terminal to print "done".

Comment: You’re accessing an index in your array that does not exist.

Comment: Check the value of `x` before you try to use it. And don't hardcode the number 6. Compare against the array count.

Comment: If x >= answer.length or x >= question.length, you can’t continue the execution of method.

Answer (score 0):

You check `if (x >= 6)` to see if the you are done, therefore when x = 5 you are not complete.  However the array holds five items, but because an array is 0-indexed there are only entries for indexes 0 to 4.  Therefore in `if answerBox.text! == answer[x]` you are will get an index out of range error as answer[5] does not exist.

You need to take this into account in your code.  I'd check for completion first as that means you cannot, whatever other logic you have, use an out of range index:

```
if x >= answers.count {
  print("Done")
  return
} else if answerBox.text = answers[x] {
  print("Correct")
  x += 1
  question.text = question[x]
} else {
  print("Wrong")
  answerBox.text = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs in the first line of your submissionButton function when you check answerBox.text! == answer[x] when x has already been incremented up to 6. (Also, as rmaddy commented below, it needs to be x >= question.count to catch it when x == 5.
Try this...

```
@IBAction func submissionButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if x >= question.count {
        print("done")
        return
    }
    if answerBox.text! == answer[x] {
        x += 1
        print("correct")
        question.text = question[x]
        answerBox.text = ""
    } else {
        print("wrong")
        answerBox.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code exactly and I am still getting an error at the line `question.text = question[x]` and the message "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Comment: `if x >= question.count {`. You need `>=`, not `>`. Really you just need `==` but `>=` is safer.